# How to remove the parent node and xml declaration in a xml file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I wish to remove the Parent node and xml declaration from the file. Below is the input file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
<Product>
    <ID>001</ID>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Designation>Developer</Designation>
</Product>
</Items>
```

I need to remove the XML declaration and parent node . Like below.

```
<Product>
    <ID>001</ID>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Designation>Developer</Designation>
</Product>
```

How could I do it using C#.NET?

Comment: you want the output like ``string``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply parse the XML with [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8), like this:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Items>
<Product>
    <ID>001</ID>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Designation>Developer</Designation>
</Product>
</Items>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var s = doc.Root.Element("Product").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Which outputs

```
<Product>
  <ID>001</ID>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Designation>Developer</Designation>
</Product>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

What if there are two or more nodes inside the root element and have to get all the child nodes. For example.

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Items>
<Product>
    <ID>001</ID>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Designation>Developer</Designation>
</Product>
<Product>
    <ID>002</ID>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
    <Designation>Tester</Designation>
</Product>
</Items>
```

How to get all the product nodes alone?